# Can we rely on any guarantees based on memory layout and default destructor

Tags: c++

A while ago we had this declaration (simplified):

Declaration 1

```
struct SomeType
{
  // allocates Implementation in SomeType's TU
  SomeType();
  // ... other stuff
  struct Implementation
  {
     std::string someAtribute1;
     std::string someAtribute2;
  }
  std::auto_ptr< Implementation> pimpl;
};
```

Some time later we changed de declaration to this (simplified):

Declaration 2

```
class OtherNameImplementation;

struct SomeType
{
   // allocates OtherNameImplementation in SomeType's TU
  SomeType();
   // ... other stuff
   std::auto_ptr< OtherNameImplementation> pimpl;
};
```

Where `OtherNameImplementation` is defined in `SomeType`'s TU, and has the exact same definition as `SomeType::Implementation` had (in Declaration 1).

Somehow we missed that `SomeType` has no defined destructor, hence the compiler generated destructor is defined in the user's TU.

The question:

For TU's that has been compiled against 'Declaration 1' Is there any form of guarantees that the behavior is "correct" when, in runtime, it uses 'Declaration 2'.

There is two reasons that I can think of, that it at least seems to 'work':

1. The compiler generated destructor should do the "right thing" since the memory layout is the same for both the Implementation-types, even though the type's name has changed.
2. We haven't noticed any implications during our Test period (there are several hundreds of applications that has this dependency)

Our target platform is Solaris, and we use Sunstudio 12.

Somehow we missed this during code review, and I know this is at least UB, and in a perfect world we would define a destructor for `SomeType` and recompile every TU that is dependent of this.

Update:

I "cross posted" this on comp.lang.c++ where Alf P. Steinbach made me realize that TU's compiled against 'Declaration 2' is leaking memory (which is rather embarrassing). Based on this we will revert to 'Declaration 1' and recompile every domain that is compiled against 'Declaration 2', hence we do not have header or ABI decoupling :) but we are in a valid state. We'll fix this in the next release cycle.

Comment: Apart from the Q,which is good to ask,Can you not re-compile all the code against new modified refactored code? IMHO it is a very bad idea to compile against one piece of code and link against another.

Comment: It might help if you defined TU and UB.

Comment: @gregg: Both terms (or, at least, the expansions of both acronyms, Translation Unit and Undefined Behaviour) are well-defined by the C++ Standard.

Comment: @Als If we could, with little effort, I wouldn't be asking this question :) Dependeing on the outcome of this, we may well be forced to do it though, and our management will not be happy...

Comment: @Tomalak: You are correct about the expanded terms.  A basic point of communication.  Why unnecessarily obfuscate the question?

Comment: @gregg: In what way is it obfuscated? If you don't know what a TU is, or what UB is, then you're almost certainly not qualified to answer this question.

Comment: THe only problem I can think of is linker problems, except the parts that changed can't be accessed outside of the TU.  If it works thus far, you're probably fine.  Just recompile/relink the other TUs ASAP.

Comment: I failed to understand TU and UB but understood the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "cross posted" this on comp.lang.c++ where Alf P. Steinbach made me realize that TU's compiled against 'Declaration 2' is leaking memory (which is rather embarrassing). Based on this we will revert to 'Declaration 1' and recompile every domain that is compiled against 'Declaration 2', hence we do not have header or ABI decoupling :) but we are in a valid state. We'll fix this in the next release cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The overlay guarantee you refer to is good if there are no base/derived classes and no virtual functions.

I don't think you're allowed to assume std::auto_ptr or std::string meet that.

Comment: I don't quite understand why std::auto_ptr or std::string wouldn't satisfy those requirement. At least with the implementation we have (RogueWave).

Comment: ...furthermore, the destructor for std::auto_ptr (which is probably inlined) just calls the destructor for the "pimpl-type" (defined in user's TU), which has no virtual/base/sub. -> calls destructors for every attribute (which is exactly the same memory wise) IMHO std::string's destructor should be called correctly if we have guarantees so far. Or do I missunderstand you?

Comment: The compiler's going to inline the destructor calls (it has to...). I suppose if you've only compiled with one compiler and never shipped the source code, you could assume that compiler rather than every compiler that's allowed to exist.